# Uploading an image to an API with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, multer

I'm trying to make an application that requires image uploading and storing, I'm using Express, Mongoose and Multer and trying to upload to MongoDB.

Currently when I try to upload an image, Multer does create a folder and store the image in that folder, but it doesn't save the item to the database and it crashes the server giving the error : `ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got itemImages\034ed9d34a3b034becdb415d67b7d193`.

Adding to the database works fine without trying to add the image with multer.

My Code:

item_controller.js:

```
const Item = require('../models/item_schema');

const addItem = (req, res) => {
    let itemData = req.body
    let itemImage = req.file.path

    Item.create(itemData, itemImage)
        .then((data) => {
            if (data) {
                res.status(201).json(data)
            }
        })
}

module.exports = {
    addItem
}
```

item_schema.js

```
const { Schema, model} = require('mongoose')

const itemSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Title field is required.']
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Description field is required.']
    },
    itemImage: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Image field is required.']
    },
    userID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: [true, 'User field is required']
    },
    categoryID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
        required: [true, 'Category field is required']
    },
    qualityID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Quality",
        required: [true, 'Quality field is required']
    },
    price: {
        type: Number
    },
    claimed:{
        type: Boolean
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = model('Item', itemSchema)
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest: 'itemImages/'});

require('dotenv').config()
require('./db')()

const { addItem } = require('./controllers/item_controller')
const { loginRequired } = require('./controllers/user_controller')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/items', upload.single('itemImage'), loginRequired, addItem)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your item_controller.js try this:

```
const addItem =  (req, res) => {
 let itemData = req.body
 let itemImage = req.file.path

 Item.create({
  title: itemData.title,
  description: description ,
  itemImage: itemImage ,
  userID: item.userID ,
  categoryID: item.categoryID ,
  qualityID: item.qualityID,
  //put all data that are required here...
 }, (err,, data)=> {
  if (err) return handleError(err) //here you custom handleError of Just res.status(400).json(err);

  res.status(201).json(data)
 })
}
```

Model.create receive as a first params all that property you want to save in your Model and second params it a closure.

Comment: Thank you! It works! So I took what you put up and just added the 'itemData.' before each of the itemData fields and it's now successfully saving the image location in the MongoDB collection. There is something interesting happening however, when it saves the image location, it's saving it as itemImages//generatedID, and I can't seem to get rid of the extra '/'. I removed the / from the end of the ````({dest: 'itemImages/'})```` in server.js, and I really expected that to have been the probelm, but it's still saving with a double / somehow, do you have any idea how this could be? Thanks again!

Comment: @Marcus I will recommend to you in you instance of multer put as a following: `const upload = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './itemImages')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})`

Comment: Thanks Luis, I've implemented what you suggest and it does make the saved file name more legible and sortable, though the double / problem persists. It doesn't seem to be breaking anything though, I can access the images in browser no problem. Hopefully it doesn't become and actual problem later on. Thanks for all your help, I appreciate it.